# Reliable, fault tolerant and scalable solution for tracking updates on different mongo collection

Tags: java, mongodb, rabbitmq, microservices

```js
//CouponCartRule - MongoDB
{
  "id": 1,

  "applicability": {
    "validFrom": "12-MAR-2017T01:00:00Z",
    "validTill": "12-MAR-2019T01:00:00Z"
  },

  "maxUsage": 100,
  "currentUsage": 99,
  "maxBudget": 1000,
  "currrentBudget": 990
}


//UniqueCoupon collection  - MongoDB
{
  "ruleId": 1,
  "couponCode": "CITIDEALMAR18",
  "currentCouponUsage": 90,
  "validFrom": "12-MAR-2018T01:00:00Z",
  "validTill": "12-APR-2018T01:00:00Z"
}

{
  "ruleId": 1,
  "couponCode": "CITIDEALAPR18",
  "currentCouponUsage": 9,
  "validFrom": "12-JAN-2018T01:00:00Z",
  "validTill": "12-FEB-2018T01:00:00Z"
}


//Order - MongoDB
{
  "id": 112,
  "total": {
    "discountCode": "CITIDEALMAR18",
    "discount": 10,
    "total": 90,
    "grandTotal": 90

  },
  "items": []
}
```

**Problem Description**

A CouponCartRule will have conditions defined for a coupon code to be applied on order.

Each shopping cart rule can have n coupons where specific conditions might be overriden.

This is done to reuse CouponCartRule but create different coupons under them and also coupons under CouponCartRule can grow to max of 10K record.

When order is succesffuly placed the order will have couponCode and discount applied.

Order collection is managed by OM team and it is very big.
We receive order add / cancel event when order is created / cancelled.

I have requirement to check if maxUsage and maxBudget is not breached during checkout.

I  am planning to listen to order add and cancel event, update usage on order add and order cancel event.

Steps

- Update currentUsage of UniqueCoupon usage [inc operator of mongo]
- Update currentUsage & budget stats of CouponCartRule using

Any suggestion on making the code idempotent if there is downtime, If there is failure in step 2. The listener would send message to DLQ and the count would be update again which is not desired.

One option that I thought of is to track and record stats at UniqueCoupon level and later aggregate at SCR level [The aggregation operation will eventually be consistent when subsequent coupon is used].

Since this code is invoked real time it should be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up proposing the below solution that is supported by our infra [rabbit mq and mongodb]. Here is the solution that was accepted after design review. Hope this helps someone who is having similar issues.

- System receives order add / cancel event from Order Management.
- If coupon code was used in order, We Upsert record into DB based on order ID.
- Order Add Event- Track coupon code, orderId, discount, couponRuleId, updated etc. Upsert based on orderId and update couponUsed flag as “APPLIED”
- Order cancel Event- Upsert orderId based on orderId and update couponUsed flag as “NOT_APPLIED”
- Have  Mongo TTL on “coupon_usage_tracker” as 3 months / 6 months.
- Trigger sync on COUPON_RULE_SUMMARY and COUPON_SUMMARY dashboard based on last by passing required data. Trigger sync mechanism is via MQ since we can have automated retry on failure via DLQ setup.

  - If trigger sync fails for either COUPON_RULE_SUMMARY and COUPON_SUMMARY then it would be updated with correct value in next coupon code usage [Eventual consistency].
  - The config collections will not have mutable states and would be strictly having configuration. This lets us cache the configs.

```js
//COUPON_USAGE_TRACKER
{
    "ruleId": 948,
    "couponCode": "TENOFF",
    "couponId": 123,
    "order": {
        "created_at": "",
        "udpated_at": "",
        "member_id": 221930,
        "member_order_count": 5,
        "publicId": "4asdff-23ewea-232",
        "id": 234123,
        "total": {
            "discount_code": "TENOFF",
            "discount": "10",
            "grand_total": 100,
            "sub_total": 10
        }
    }
}

//COUPON_RULE_SUMMARY
{
    "ruleId": 948,
    "last_update_at": "",
    "currentUsage": 100,
    "currentBudget": 1000
}

//COUPON_SUMMARY
{
    "ruleId": 948,
    "couponId": 948,
    "last_update_at": "",
    "currentUsage": 100,
    "currentBudget": 1000
 
}
```

[image: SYSTEM DESIGN FOR THE SOLUTION]